# Folding specific sections of code in vim

Tags: vim, python

I'm wondering if it is possible to automatically fold only specific sections of code in vim (specifically for python files).

I'm currently using the indent fold method. And I would like to only fold an indented block if the header matches a pattern.

For instance, if I'm in a file with this function, I would like all blocks that start with Example: or References: to be automatically folded, but I don't want anything else to be folded.

Is there a simple way to do this?

```
def spawn_background_process(func, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Run a function in the background
    (like rebuilding some costly data structure)

    References:
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046603/is-it-possible-to-run-function-in-a-subprocess-without-threading-or-writing-a-se
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063963/python-is-thread-still-running

    Args:
        func (function):

    CommandLine:
        python -m utool.util_parallel --test-spawn_background_process

    Example:
        >>> # DISABLE_DOCTEST
        >>> from utool.util_parallel import *  # NOQA
        >>> import utool as ut
        >>> import time
        >>> from os.path import join
        >>> # build test data
        >>> fname = 'test_bgfunc_output.txt'
        >>> dpath = ut.get_app_resource_dir('utool')
        >>> ut.ensuredir(dpath)
        >>> fpath = join(dpath, fname)
        >>> # ensure file is not around
        >>> sleep_time = 1
        >>> ut.delete(fpath)
        >>> assert not ut.checkpath(fpath, verbose=True)
        >>> def backgrond_func(fpath, sleep_time):
        ...     import utool as ut
        ...     import time
        ...     print('[BG] Background Process has started')
        ...     time.sleep(sleep_time)
        ...     print('[BG] Background Process is writing')
        ...     ut.write_to(fpath, 'background process')
        ...     print('[BG] Background Process has finished')
        ...     #raise AssertionError('test exception')
        >>> # execute function
        >>> func = backgrond_func
        >>> args = (fpath, sleep_time)
        >>> kwargs = {}
        >>> print('[FG] Spawning process')
        >>> threadid = ut.spawn_background_process(func, *args, **kwargs)
        >>> assert threadid.is_alive() is True, 'thread should be active'
        >>> print('[FG] Spawned process. threadid=%r' % (threadid,))
        >>> # background process should not have finished yet
        >>> assert not ut.checkpath(fpath, verbose=True)
        >>> print('[FG] Waiting to check')
        >>> time.sleep(sleep_time + .1)
        >>> print('[FG] Finished waiting')
        >>> # Now the file should be there
        >>> assert ut.checkpath(fpath, verbose=True)
        >>> assert threadid.is_alive() is False, 'process should have died'
    """
    import utool as ut
    func_name = ut.get_funcname(func)
    name = 'mp.Progress-' + func_name
    proc_obj = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, name=name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    #proc_obj.isAlive = proc_obj.is_alive
    proc_obj.start()
    return proc_obj
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this, you just have to write yourself a [custom fold function](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/).

Put the following code in `.vim/after/ftplugin/python/folding.vim` (creating directories and files if not present):

```
function! ExampleFolds(lnum)
  let s:thisline = getline(a:lnum)
  if match(s:thisline, '^\s*Example:$') >= 0
    return '>1'
  elseif match(s:thisline, '^\s*$') >= 0
    return '0'
  else
    return '='
endfunction

setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldexpr=ExampleFolds(v:lnum)
```

You will still need to adapt that function a bit to suit your needs. What it does right now is to start a fold with foldlevel 1 whenever it meets an `Example:` block. The fold includes all following lines till either a new example block is there (starting a new fold) or an empty line closes it.

Besides the link, check `:h foldexpr` and `:h foldlevel`.